# Where can I play Naruto Ninpou any version with someone else for free?

Tags: mods, warcraft-3, warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne

Where can I play Naruto Ninpou any version with someone else for free? I mean the game which is the mode for Warcraft 3 Throzen Throne. And I mean legally.

Comment: Is "in Warcraft 3" not a good answer?

Comment: Why did I get so many down votes without any explanations?

Comment: You're asking about a Naruto game, and a recommendation on where to play it (which is against our policy), but also tagged the question with Warcraft 3 tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Nowhere

You need to buy Warcraft 3 before you can play mods in it.  I doubt Blizzard will start giving it away anytime soon.  They haven't given away Warcraft 1 yet.

Comment: It's true that they haven't given away Warcraft 1 for free (AFAIK), however, they DID recently release [Starcraft 1 for free download.](https://www.pcmag.com/news/352746/blizzard-offers-original-starcraft-for-free)  You need a BattleNet account, but signing up for that is also free.  So, maybe he just needs to wait another ten years...

Comment: So there is a glimmer of hope, but they also sued bnetd into oblivion which leaves me doubtful.